# move a value from one header row to another header row in a dataframe - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, row

I have created a dataframe from a `groupby.mean()`. 
However when I try to call a row from the df it returns an error.
From examining the df I have noticed that I have two header rows, can someone please help me move `attr_time` into the first column of the first header row, or at least explain to me why there are two header rows?

Im very new to python, sorry if this is very basic.

[image: two header rows]